# if $f:(a,b) \rightarrow (c,d)$ is a differentiable surjection and $f'(x)$ is never zero then $f$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis

There is a theorem in our analysis book which says:

if $f:(a,b) \rightarrow (c,d)$ is a diffrentiable surjection and $f'(x)$ is never zero then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

This is the proof of the book:

if $f'$ is never zero then by the intermediate value property of derivatives, it is either always positive or always negative. We assume for all $x$ that $f'(x)>0$. If $a<s<t<b$ then by the Mean Value Theorem there exists $\theta \in (s,t)$ such that $f(t)-f(s)=f'(\theta)(t-s)>0$. Thus $f$ is strictly monotone. Differentiability implies continuity, so $f$ is a homeomorphism $(a,b) \rightarrow (c,d)$.

As I know for proving that $f$ is a homeomorphism, We should prove that $f$ is a continuous bijection and $f^{-1}$ is also continuous. But in this proof the book just proved that $f$ is a continuous bijection, what about continuity of $f^{-1}$? Am I Right? If not, what is my mistake then?

Comment: You are right. It's just that there is a theorem that states that a continuous bijective mapping defined on an interval has a continuous inverse.

Comment: @LeBtz Does this theorem any name or something that I can find it?

Comment: Actually Mark Joshi almost proved that. You just have to replace $f'>0$ with $f$ strictly increasing (or decreasing) which you always have for a bijective continuous function on an interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have to show that the image of every open set is open. Take $f'>0$ everywhere WLOG. (work with -f otherwise)
 Consider an open set $U$ and $x \in U.$ Take $y < x< z$ all in $U.$ Then 
$$
f(y) < f(x) < f(z) 
$$
since $f'$ is never zero. So the image set contains $(f(y),f(z))$ that is an open interval containing $f(x)$ so the image of $U$ is open as claimed and we are done.

Comment: I know that $f$ is continuous. what I want to prove is continuity of $f^{-1}$. So, I think for proving by your approach we need to prove that the **preimage** of every open set is open. (I'm not sure but I think proving that the image of every open set is open will prove the continuity of $f$ ).

Comment: No, the proof is correct. If you want to prove that preimages of $f^{-1}$ are open you can aswell prove that images of $f$ are open (of open sets) which he did in this case.

Comment: @LeBtz Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The continiuity of $f^{-1}$ follows from the equality $(f^{-1} )' (y) =\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1} (y))}$ which shows that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable and hence continuous.